# Split a list of items based on their defined sum limit

Tags: python

I am looking for a solution to the following:

```
oList = [400,250,750,800,125,500,550,100]
limit = 1000
list1 = []
nList = []
li = 0
for v in oList:
    li += v
    if li > limit:
        nList.append(v)
        list1 = set(oList) - set(nList)   

print(list1)

list1 [400, 250]
```

What I am looking for is:

```
list1 [400, 250]
list2 [750]
list3 [800]
list4 [125, 500]
list5 [550, 100]
```

A list of lists will suffice as a result, thank you.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no element will be higher than `limit`? If not, what would you want the behaviour to be then?

Comment: two observations. if a value in `oList` is greater than `limit`, what's the course of action. Second, `list3` can also be setup as `[800, 125]` as it totals to `925`. Why did you consider `list3` as `[800]` ?

Comment: The second is a typo mistake :); the first should throw an error, no much trouble in there i guess :)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with a current sum that determines if the elements should be appended to the list (repeatedly calling sum() would make the solution slower). However, to get a list of list you will need to chose between appending a new sublist (and resetting the total) or appending to the last list in the list of lists.

Here's how you could do it:

```
def splitsum(L,S):
    result,t = [[]],0
    for n in L:
        r,v,t = (result,[n],n) if t+n>S else (result[-1],n,t+n)
        r.append(v) # append n to last list or [n] to list of lists
    return result
```

output:

```
L = [400,250,750,800,125,500,550,100]
print(splitsum(L,1000))

[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500], [550, 100]]
```

Comment: Wow, this is super awesome code. very nice use of reference usage of r and result. I learnt something new today

Comment: Guys, you are really awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work for what you want.
Here we keep all the lists inside a data variable. We only add a new list to it if needed. Therefor we are also working/adding items to the last list inside the data variable

```
items = [400,250,750,800,125,500,550,100]
limit = 1000 
data = [[]]


for item in items:
    if sum(data[len(data)-1]) > limit: # if the current list we are adding to would exceed the limit, make a new list. 
        data.append([])
    data[len(data)-1].append(item) # add the current item to the latest list
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you want to do this via `set` difference? Because that might not be able to correctly handle a case where your list contains duplicates, like `oList = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]` and `limit = 250` in that case I feel like your code would only return `list1 = [100]`.

So what you want to do is split a list into chunks such that the sum of each chunk is below a given limit (but as close to it as possible), right?

You're already pretty close... I'd just pick a for-loop to go over all the original lists items and then start a new "to-be-added" list as needed:

```py
chunks = []
new_list = []
current_sum = 0
for item in oList:
  if current_sum + item < limit:
    # item still fits, add it to the current list
    new_list.append(item)
    current_sum += item
  else:
    # item doesn't fit. finish up the current list
    # and start a fresh list, beginning with this item!
    chunks.append(new_list)
    current_sum = item
    new_list = [item]
```

Note: In this code, if a *single* item of your list is already larger than the limit, it will just get its own list.

Answer (score 0):

1. Step 1: create a `temp_list`.
2. Step 2: Add items to `temp_list` if the sum is less than `limit`.
3. Step 3: If the sum is greater than `limit`, then add the `temp_list`
   to `new_list`. Do this till the last iteration.
4. Step 4: Once you have finished iterating through all the items,
   check if `temp_list` is empty. If not, then there are elements in
   the `temp_list` that must be added to the `new_list`. Add then and
   you now have a new list of all items where the limit is less than or
   equal to `limit`.

Please note that there may be situations where an element can greater than `limit`. The code is setup to create the element as an individual `list`. If you want this to be excluded, it requires a few tweaks.

Here's how I would do it.

```
oList = [400,250,750,800,125,500,550,100]
limit = 1000
list1 = []
temp_list = []
for item in oList:
    if sum(temp_list) + item > limit:
        list1.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = [item]
    else:
        temp_list.append(item)
if temp_list:
    list1.append(temp_list)

print (list1)
```

Output of this will be:

```
[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500], [550, 100]]
```

Example where an element is greater than `limit`.

```
oList = [400,250,750,800,125,500,1500,550,100]
```

The output will be as follows. Note that 1500, ended up as an element.

```
[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500], [1500], [550, 100]]
```

If you want to exclude 1500 from being added as an element, you can use this code as the first statement inside the for loop `for item in oList:`

```
if item > limit: continue
```

Then the output will be as shown below (excludes `1500`).

```
[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500], [550, 100]]
```

Note the small difference in the output when you use include or exclude the above condition.

Input data:

```
oList = [400,250,750,800,125,500,1500,300, 550,100]
```

With the condition to exclude any value greater than `limit`.

Output will be:

```
[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500, 300], [550, 100]]
```

If you do not exclude, then it creates

```
[[400, 250], [750], [800, 125], [500], [1500], [300, 550, 100]]
```

Here `500` is a new element in the second option while the first option used `500` and `300` to create a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme: keep a running total while iterating; when the limit is exceeded save the current list of items, reset the total, start a new list.

```
a = [400,250,750,800,125,500,550,100]
x = 0
b = []
c = []
for n in a:
    x += n
    if x <= 1000:
        b.append(n)
    else:
        c.append(b)
        b = [n]
        x = n
if b != c[-1]: c.append(b)
print(c)
```