# Group list of files based on their size

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a sorted list of files.
I need to make a nested list from a list, grouping the files as follows (without changing the original list sequence):
so that the total size of the grouped files does not exceed 100 Kilobytes.

list   -    `['Doc3.pdf', 'Doc4.pdf', 'Doc2.pdf', 'Doc5.pdf', 'Doc1.pdf', 'Doc6.pdf']`

file size -      `30KB        60KB        120KB       20KB        10KB        35KB`

output - `[['Doc3.pdf', 'Doc4.pdf'], ['Doc2.pdf'], ['Doc5.pdf', 'Doc1.pdf', 'Doc6.pdf']]`

To find out the file size I use

```
os.path.getsize("nameOfFile")
```

Comment: May this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538511/17457846

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```py
# import os

max_group_size = 100000
docs = ['Doc3.pdf', 'Doc4.pdf', 'Doc2.pdf', 'Doc5.pdf', 'Doc1.pdf', 'Doc6.pdf']

grouped_docs, cur_size_total = [[]], 0
for d in docs:
    cur_doc_size = os.path.getsize(d)

    if (cur_size_total + cur_doc_size) > max_group_size:
        cur_size_total = 0
        grouped_docs.append([])

    grouped_docs[-1].append(d)
    cur_size_total += cur_doc_size
```

`grouped_docs` should look like your desired output